# Посимвольное кодирование сообщений на питон

Tags: python

Вводится m сообщений различной длины, составленных из символов некоторого алфавита. Программа кодирует все символы алфавита равномерным двоичным кодом с числом разрядов, определяемым по формуле 2, и выводит на экран m кодовых комбинаций, полученных путем объединения двоичных кодов, соответствующих символам введенных сообщений.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так вопрос-то  в чём?

Comment: Нужно программа которая, кодирует все символы алфавита равномерным двоичным кодом с числом разрядов, определяемым по формуле 2, и выводит на экран m кодовых комбинаций, полученных путем объединения двоичных кодов, соответствующих символам введенных сообщений.

Comment: тут разбираются с проблемами и ошибками в коде. Но для этого должен быть код. А так вам к фрилансерам. они напишут